Are they linearly independent?
Let $ V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} $, and consider the following subsets of $ V $:

$ X = \left\{ f_A \mid A \neq \emptyset, A \subset \mathbb{N} \right\} $, where $ f_A: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} $ is defined as:
$
   f_A(n) = 
   \begin{cases} 
   1 & \text{if } n \in A, \\
   0 & \text{if } n \notin A.
   \end{cases}
   $

$ Y = \left\{ g \circ \sigma \mid \sigma: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \text{ is a bijection} \right\} $, where $ g \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} $ is an injective function.


I am trying to prove that the vector space $ V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} $ over $ \mathbb{R} $ has uncountably infinite dimension. To approach this, I considered the set of all re-arrangements of the real sequence $ \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $. Upon examining certain subsets of this set, I found them to be linearly independent. However, I am unable to generalize this result to an arbitrary case.
To extend the idea, I generalized the problem to the set $ Y $, but I still couldn’t make progress. The set $ X $ also seemed promising, but I am unable to find a proper way to prove its linear independence.
Could someone provide insight or guidance on how to prove the linear independence of the sets $ X $ and $ Y $? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The set $X$ is obviously not linearly independent. Look at some example elements. Same for $Y$.

Further hint: When is $f_A+f_B=f_{A\cup B}$?

Thanks. The example $ (1,0,0,0,\dots) + (0,1,0,0,\dots) = (1,1,0,0,\dots) $ clearly shows that the set $ X $ is not linearly independent. I now understand this. Is there any restriction on the set $ X $ to make it linearly independent while still being uncountably infinite?
